# Why does my TexMaker output have this terrible kerning?

Tags: packages, texmaker, article, kerning, output

I am writing a research article using TexMaker. The article uses the following packages as preamble:

```
\ifx\directlua\undefined\ifx\XeTeXcharclass\undefined
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                           %pdftex engine
  \else\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]\fi %xetex engine
  \else\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]\fi %luatex engine
\usepackage[sort&compress,square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[big, online]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

dgruyter is a package that can be found here https://www.degruyter.com/publication/journal_key/NANOPH/downloadAsset/NANOPH_LaTeX_Article_Template.zip together with a template for the article I'm trying to write.

But the output looks very bad. This is how the output looks like on TexMaker:

[image]

Compare this to the output that I get with the same exact file but using Overleaf:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? This is not the only issue with the file, as TexMaker isn't able to compile the bibliography, but that's a different matter and will be asked in a separate question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. TeXmaker is just a front-end to a TeX distribution and, as such, doesn't perform any typesetting tasks. Please do tell us which TeX distribution and when it was last updated. Aside: Overleaf uses TeXLive as its underlying TeX distribution.

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your .log file (for your bibliography problem you will have to run bibtex)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz here is a link to the entire log: https://pastebin.com/rL0MmsmG

Comment: Install the cm-super package.

Comment: You really should not look at the output as long as there are errors in your document. Fix these first, then worry about aesthetics.

Comment: @Mico I am completely unaware of what this all means. I'm using the most basic Texmaker portable installation. I guess the answer you need is "MiKTeX"? I'm not sure about the version, it might be 2.9, but I have no idea how to check.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano Open a command prompt, and type `pdflatex --version`. (If you're unsure about how to open a command prompt, which OS are you using?)

Comment: The first line in the log file should tell you which TeX distribution is in use. E.g., a recent log file of mine says `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.12.8)  8 DEC 2023 13:50.` This reveals that `TeX Live 2023` is the TeX distriubution and that pdfLaTeX (the format) was last updated on `2023.12.8`, i.e., earlier today.

Comment: @Teepeemm Windows says that it cannot recognize the command. I want to remark here that my installations of TexMaker and MikTex are portable. They are not installed in Windows.

Comment: @Mico ```This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.12 Portable) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.1.5)  8 DEC 2023 17:13``` this is the first line in the log I linked above.

Comment: you could delete all of `\ifx\directlua\undefined\ifx\XeTeXcharclass\undefined
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                           %pdftex engine
  \else\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]\fi %xetex engine
  \else\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]\fi %luatex engine` which does basically nothing other than set values you get anyway by default,

Comment: So you're using MikTeX, and it was updated back in January of this year. Do try to run an update on MikTEX.

Comment: The portable miktex has its own command line where you can run such commands.

Comment: unlike texlive in miketex you need to choose to install the cm-super package in the miktex console

Comment: @UlrikeFischer where do I find it? The only command line I can find is a miktex-portable.cmd file, but when I execute it, it closes immediately, even as admin.

Comment: @Mico I tried running every executable I could find with the name "MikTex" next to it, including miktex-update, miktex-console, and miktex-mf, but none of them actually did anything. Would you recommend a full reinstall of miktex?

Comment: I meant the small menu in windows beside the task bar https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition